# Loading Csv file from Qt resources

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to read a csv file that I've added to my project's resources.
Yet, when I try to open the file, it fails.

```
std::ifstream csvFile;
csvFile.open(fileName);
```

This is how I try to open it. Other files in the resources are ok (all others are images, and they load and display correctly).
I'm using Qt5.7 with Qt Creator 4.0.2

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The failure is caused by the fact that Qt resources are not really files which can be opened by each and every tool working with files. Instead, the contents of files added to Qt project's resources are [built into](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#compiled-in-resources) the resulting executable.

The good news is that Qt has facilities which allow you to work with such resources as if they were real files:

```
QString myResourceFile = ":/resources/file.csv";
QFile file(myResourceFile);
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QByteArray contents = file.readAll();
    // process file's contents
}
else {
    // Whoops, something went wrong, bad path to resource?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but still the file won't open. errorString() show "Unknown error". Double checked the path. Anything else?

Comment: First, see what `file.error()` returns i.e. what kind of error from [this list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#FileError-enum) occurs.

Comment: It returns 0 :-(

Comment: Also, ensure the path to the file within your `.qrc` file is correct.

Comment: The symptoms you describe seem like [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45259). I.e the path to the resource is incorrect, `QFile` simply can't report that correctly.

Comment: you might need to force initialization of your resources by calling Q_INIT_RESOURCE() with the base name of the .qrc file

Comment: Triple checked all paths and called Q_INIT_RESOURCE, still nothing.

Comment: Can you try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in which the problem reproduces? Without that it's hard to guess what that might be - maybe a friend or a colleague of yours has replaced the colon with a similarly looking Unicode symbol in the path to your resource file and that's why the whole thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the checkbox from shadow build in Projects

[image]

QT Creator version: 6.4.3